# Best practices to minimize latency in a globally available application using a SQL db?

Tags: postgresql, performance

We have a globally available application that uses a SQL database. We have a fairly low number of users and load on database is low, however latency for users located far from the database server is a bit of a concern. I'm looking for an advice on recommended best practices and techniques to minimize latency and enhance overall performance in this scenario. What strategies should we consider implementing to optimize performance and reduce latency in our globally accessible application, given the low user count and low database load?

Comment: Use few bigger statements rather than many small ones. Use [pipeline mode](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/pipeline-mode-better-performance-on-slow-network/) wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a connection pool from the application side or from database side (ex: PGBouncer) and reuse existing connections to avoid keeping creating new ones.
Then it is more network implementation. Keeping the database close to the clients is the best option for latency.